# using dynamodb SET to append to a string set

Tags: javascript, amazon-dynamodb

I have looked at recent posts and nothing on them has worked for me. I have a string set called "friendRequests" in my DynamoDB table and I am trying to append an element to it. However, I keep getting many errors when I try to call db.updateItem with these parameters. Here is my current code, the error is with ExpressionAttributeValues but I have probably spent an hour changing my syntax to no avail.

```
    var params = {
    TableName: "users",
    Key: { "username": { "S": addFriendInfo.friendUsername } },
    UpdateExpression: "SET friendRequests = list_append(friendRequests, :newFriend)",
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ':newFriend': { "SS" : [addFriendInfo.username] }
    }
}
```

That is my code above. addFriendInfo.username / friendUsername are both just strings. This currently gives me a   'Invalid UpdateExpression: Incorrect operand type for operator or function; operator or function: list_append, operand type: SS'. I have tried many things. Can anyone point me in right direction to fixing this damn syntax?

Answer (score 6):

As the [DynamoDB documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.NamingRulesDataTypes.html#HowItWorks.DataTypes) explains, DynamoDB has two similar but distinct types - a **list** and a **set**. A list is an ordered list of items of any type, while a set is a non-empty, non-ordered collection of items of the same type. The "SS" type you used is a "set of strings". This is distinct from a "list", and you cannot use `list_append` on sets, as the error message tells you.

To add an element to a set (or create a new set if it doesn't yet exist) you can use the `ADD` operation, e.g., `ADD friendRequests :newFriend`.